# find and replace a character in my file names with a python re

Tags: python, regex, replace

basically I want to change the first `"."` to `"_"`
`Name.1001.ext` to `Name_1001.ext`:

I have something like this but it is returning the original name:

```
print re.sub(r'\D+.\d+\.$',r'\D+_\d+\.$',fileName)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Regex` seems like an overkill for this example, you should probably go for `str.replace()` here:

```
In [16]: strs="Name.1001.ext"

In [17]: strs.replace(".","_",1) # now only 1 occurrence of the 
                                 # substring is going to be replaced 
Out[17]: 'Name_1001.ext'
```

> S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.